# Freeswitch allow any user to register

Tags: freeswitch

I am currently trying to set up a freeswitch server for a game, the way it works is that the game client trys to register a random user id with freeswitch server. is there a way to have freeswitch register any user from any ip without having to add them to the directory folder? basically disable any and all security.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can register any user on FreeSWITCH without authentication. There are two parameter in sofia profile for register and call without authentication.

**accept-blind-auth** : Accept any authentication without actually checking (not a good feature for most people)
`<param name="accept-blind-auth" value="true"/>`.

**auth-calls** : Users in the directory can have "auth-acl" parameters applied to them so as to restrict users access to a predefined ACL or a CIDR.
`<param name="auth-calls" value="$${internal_auth_calls}"/>`. Value can be "false" to disable authentication on this profile, meaning that when calls come in the profile will *not* send an auth challenge to the caller.

For more information https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia.conf.xml#accept-blind-auth/.

Comment: If you are using XML, please use `backticks` in posts, otherwise the tags won't show up. There is a preview window so you can see your posts before you publish them.

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely do this with kamailio in front of FreeSWITCH. I'm not sure if FreeSWITCH alone can do this, will check it out over the weekend.

Comment: the thing is actually not in registering, but in sending a call to a user: in order to make a `bridge` to `user/xxx`, you need a valid user ID.  I guess you will have to end up with Kamailio anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Include the following line in your **sofia profile :**

```
<param name="accept-blind-reg" value="true"/>
```

and adjust corresponding acl in it. The same approach applies to calls authentication - see Auth and Registration sections here:

wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia.conf.xml

P.S. running freeswitch that way is unsafe and is a *really* bad idea.