# Contradictory settings in FreeSWITCH SIP profile

Tags: acl, freeswitch

I am working with a simple FreeSWITCH installation, with the vanilla demo configuration.  I see that the Internal SIP profile contains:

```
  <param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="domains"/>
  <param name="auth-calls" value="$${internal_auth_calls}"/>
```

The first line means that if a caller's IP is on the 'domains' list that they do NOT need to authenticate.  The second line means that in order to use this SIP profile the user must be authenticated (internal_auth_calls is true).

Aren't these two lines contradictory?  Why allow a user to not authenticate for this SIP profile, and then say they must authenticate to use this SIP profile?

Comment: As I understand *apply-inbound-acl* this params use for allow register with IP or only domain and *auth-calls* use for restrict users access to a predefined ACL or a CIDR.
So far you need to authenticate to route call using freeswitch

Comment: This link may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802615/4781696